# Implementing OAuth provider in Java

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, token

What is the fastest/easiest way to get an OAuth provider running in Java? Specifically, I need to authorize third-party apps to access certain web services (I'm thinking token authentication using OAuth).

I've been looking at Jersey's OAuth extension, but as mentioned [here](http://n2.nabble.com/Help-with-creating-an-OAuth-Service-Provider-using-Jersey-OAuth-Api-tp3879487p4031208.html), it doesn't provide a full-fledged Service Provider.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a few Java libraries out there for OAuth. Specifically, I'd have a look at [this one](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/). I haven't used it myself, but there is an example for running an OAuth Service Provider.

There's a list of libraries available on the OAuth website: http://oauth.net/code

Comment: I did eventually go for the net.oauth Java package. The net.oauth.example.provider was pretty useful.

I also came across the Spring's OAuth tutorial: http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/tutorial.html. But since I'm not running Spring, it wasn't very useful for me.

Comment: Since so many people have viewed this, I just want to add that I took the example servlets in net.oauth.example.provider.servlets to handle OAuth (barely modified). oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/oauth-provider The JavaScript client helped a lot to test my implementation. oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript For protected resources, just make sure you validate the OAuthAccessor.

Comment: @Paul the above link [this one]http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/ is broken