# OAuth 1.0 or 2.0 server implementation? Native mobile application authentication

Tags: java, mobile, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

There are lots of resources describing OAuth usage in terms of clients, Facebook/LinkedIn/Twitter API usages. This is ok. But I am interested in OAuth server implementation. The aim is to have the web application which also can be accessible by the mobile devices (native applications), so I need to setup OAuth on my back-end Java server. So I would like to know how LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter implemented OAuth on their server side, and distinguish users between auth_token-s and grant the corresponding access (some kind database mapping - auth_token = user identity?).

Or maybe there is the better way to authenticate mobile user (I'm going to use REST style services for back-end)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter have implemented OAuth following the specifications for [OAuth 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849)  (Twitter LinkedIn) and the [draft for OAuth 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22) (Facebook, LinkedIn).

I would suggest going for OAuth 1, or OAuth 2 User Agent Flow. If your mind is set on OAuth that is. You could always go for [simple basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465872/how-to-secure-restful-web-services-provider/8466204#8466204) to begin with and focus on the really hard parts, namely the design of your API itself.

If your mind is set on OAuth, check out this list of code libraries: http://oauth.net/code/. And also read up on the specifications, if you want to implement an OAuth provider, you have to know and understand the specs. Otherwise you are in for a world of pain looking for out-of-the-box libraries that will solve everything "OAuthy" for you.

Comment: Could you, please, also clarify if you are familiar with the OAuth spec - does it specify how to generate token, and how map tokens to the user identity (runtime hashmap, database, etc.), or this part is missing in the spec, and it is up to provider implementation, so Twitter/Facebook/LinkedIn each of them have their own provider implementation? Maybe, you know any presentation/docs available on OAuth architecture/implementation by these companies?

Comment: Token and secret generation is not specified, it is indeed up to the implementor with the following statement: `urged to err on the side of caution, and use the longest secrets reasonable`. I.e use a tough encryption algorithm, with truly random and complex salts. When it comes to OAuth 1 read this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth. It describes what an implementor of a client needs to do, and therefore also what you as a provider need to adhere to and support. I have not found any more in detail articles on implementation. In my view it comes down to understanding the specs.

Comment: Another point is that for the problem domain of OAuth 1, the consumer (client) and provider (server) actually do the same thing, they sign parameters with the same secrets, so a client library for signing requests can easily be used to sign requests for validation on the server side. The difference is that once that is done, one part sends responses and the other receives them. For OAuth 2 there is more of a difference depending on what flow you choose. The User Agent Flow seems to be the most commonly adapted. But keep in mind that OAuth 2 is still a specification draft.