# Implementing OAuth 2.0 Provider using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, oauth-2.0

I need to implement the OAuth 2.0 Provider using Coldfusion. Do you know of any library I could use? Only thing I've found is [this](http://oauth.riaforge.org/), but it's based on the Core 1.0 specification.

What are you thoughts on this? Maybe I should use the [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150801/implementing-oauth-provider-in-java) libraries? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pre-existing Java provider implementation and use ColdFusion's cfinvoke/cfobject syntax to implement the provider in your ColdFusion application.  The oAuth site maintains a list of server/provider implementations by language [here](http://oauth.net/2/).  Using this sort of solution might even give you more flexibility in the long run if you have other Java apps that need to provide oAuth provider services.

Comment: I have access to manage certain things related to CF on the site, but I wish they had an "admin can mark an answer correct" function. I lieu of that, I will say, "This is the Way".

Answer (score 0):

To implement OpenID 2.0 Auth framework using ColdFusion go to [this](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/) link and download "OpenID CFC" Library.

This is really a nice one to implement OpenID 2.0 using ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is this OAuth library from Harry Klein used in several ColdFusion projects involving OAuth 2.0 (IE. twitter clients) - http://oauth.riaforge.org/

Comment: That's the same I've put in the question and I've been using it in several projects as well, but in this one I need to be the provider - not the consumer.

Comment: I thought both implementations where there client and server.