# Apache velocity for user login system, is this a good language choice?

Tags: java, velocity

First off, is this even possible? From what iv'e used velocity servlets for in the past, I have never used them to retain information or sessions , just to be queried and return data to the page contexts. I have been doing a project in Velocity and now need to make the choice to either use velocity (if it is possible for this task) or something else. If I can't use velocity, or if there is a better option, what would it be?

Comment: Ideally you should authentic with a 3rd party using OAuth (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: There's some details on running your own OAuth provider here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150801/implementing-oauth-provider-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Apache Velocity is not a language, it is a template engine with a distinct syntax.

Comment: either way, this comment is not helpful if you're not going to offer any advice

Comment: @YossiShriki, because you didn't tell you what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your need: should you use Apache Velocity as a template engine for your dynamic site, how would you then add the authentication feature to your site?

Velocity itself only does the rendering of the pages - to use it in the context of a web application, you need some kind of framework. There are tons of frameworks out there, the simplest one being [Apache Velocity Tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/), which exposes to the Velocity view several tools belonging to one of the three nested scopes (*request*, *session* and *application*).

Then, to add authentication to your site, you will need some kind of storage for logins and passwords. If you go the database way, you can try [Velosurf](http://velosurf.sourceforge.net/), a specific Velocity Tool dedicated to database access. Velosurf contains an AuthenticationFilter which can fulfills your needs.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Velosurf.